# Adding Timestamp to Print Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently writing myself a program in python 3.7 and was wanting to add a timestamp to the front of my printing in the format:

```
<hh:mm:ss> WhateverImPrinting
```

I took a look at other forums and I get some code which used sys.stdout, overwriting the text using the write function.

My issue is it is returning the timestamp both before and after my print.

e.g. `<14:21:51> Hello<14:21:51>`

This should be:

```
<14:21:51> Hello
```

My code:

```
old_f = sys.stdout  # Get old print output


class PrintTimestamp:
    # @staticmethod
    def write(self, x):
        old_f.write("<{}> {}".format(str(pC.Timestamp.hhmmss()), x))

    # @staticmethod
    def flush(self):
        pass


sys.stdout = PrintTimestamp()    # Set new print output
```

I have run this after all my classes and functions, but before `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply override `print` function in Python 3.x:

```
from datetime import datetime

old_print = print

def timestamped_print(*args, **kwargs):
  old_print(datetime.now(), *args, **kwargs)

print = timestamped_print
```

then

```
print("Test")
```

should print

```
2019-09-30 01:23:44.67890 Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
from datetime import datetime

class PrintTimeStamp():
   def write(self,x):
       ts = str(datetime.now.hour())+":"+str(datetime.now().minute)+":"+str(datetime.now().second)
       print("<{}> {}".format(str(ts),x)

pts = PrintTimeStamp()
pts.write("test")
```